# Scheduled Job equivalent functionality in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks, export-to-excel

I have a requirement in my MVC app.

I had an export to excel functionality that is taking 3 mins of time (user clicks on a export button and waits on). 
This export downloads an excel that has multiple worksheets after applying certain rules on the data.
These rules are datamanipulations plus applying colors on the cells belonging to certain columns.

Inorder to avoid the wait time, I was asked to develop a code with in the MVC app that can run like a scheduled job.
This job has to export the excel to a dedicated folder with in the network on the scheduled time (daily once).
Also i was asked to develop a web page within the app which has links to download these excels.

Quesions here (Any help would be appreciated) :

1. I have chosen Quartz.NET to implement this requirement. This is an open source (to my little knowledge) that can 
   provide the facility to schedule a job (class developed in .NET). Is it the right choice or would there be any implications in future?
2. Is it really needed to develop a job like code or any other way of coding can address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Quartz.net, but I do know that trying to run background/scheduled tasks from within the same process as the MVC application can be problematic.

Ref 1: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/

Ref 2: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Essentially, you can't guarantee that the process will complete correctly when running it due to how IIS handles app pools (which is where you MVC process runs: assuming hosting on IIS anyway).

You mention running a scheduled task *within your MVC app*.  Again, this is incorrect.  Why can't you just slap a console app project into the solution and drive the code from there, then put it on the server and use the Windows Task Scheduler?

In terms of background tasks, the "correct" way to do this is to send a command from your MVC app to some sort of message queue, which can then ensure that the command doesn't get dropped.  I've used RabbitMQ in the past (a middleware message broker).  Perhaps this is the aim of Quartz.net.

This setup typically involves another app (for me, usually a console app run on the server) that receives the command message from the message queue and runs in it's own process, entirely separate from MVC and thus the issues inherent with IIS AppPools and background tasks.

A lot of work, really... one would think it'd be easier, but that's the surefire way to do it and maintain the integrity of the task to be run.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. you have a valid point. I will research more on Quartz.Net. I still have the doubt if it runs the scheduled task with in the same process as MVC. But your reply definitely helps. Thanks again

Comment: I went through your links. Ref2 has recommened Quartz .NET as one of the solution. Thanks for those pointers !! It helped.